# How to create sub arrays with help of parent id

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here is my collected array.

```
$raw_ar = Array ( 
0 => Array ( 'ID' => 6, 'pageTitle' => 'First', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/1', 'parentID' => 0 ),
1 => Array ( 'ID' => 7, 'pageTitle' => 'Second', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/2', 'parentID' => 6 ),
2 => Array ( 'ID' => 8, 'pageTitle' => 'Third', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/3', 'parentID' => 6 ) ,
3 => Array ( 'ID' => 9, 'pageTitle' => 'Four', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/4', 'parentID' => 0 ) 
) ;
```

And my result should be like this

```
$final_ar = array(

  0  => array ( 'ID' => 6, 'pageTitle' => 'First', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/1', 'parentID' => 0 , 

    'sub_items' => array( 
         0 => array('ID' => 7, 'pageTitle' =>'second', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/2', 'parentID' => 6),
         1 => array('ID' => 8, 'pageTitle' => 'Third', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/3', 'parentID' => 6),
     )
  ), 
  1 => array('ID' => 9, 'pageTitle' => 'Four', 'pageContent' => 'http://localhost/cms/4', 'parentID' => 0)
);
```

And here is my code

```
$final_ar = array();

foreach ($raw_ar as $value) {
if($value['parentID'] ==0){
    $final_ar[] = $value;
}
else{
    $pID = $value['parentID'];
    foreach ($final_ar as $value1) {
        //echo $value1['ID'].'-'.$pID;
        if($value1['ID'] == $pID){
            //if(isset($value1['sub_items'])){
                $value1['sub_items'][] = $value;
            //}else
                //$value1['sub_items'] = $value;
        }
        $temp_ar[] = $value1;
    }
    $exist = 0; 
    foreach ($final_ar as $key => $val) {
        # code...
        if($val['ID'] == $temp_ar['ID']){
            unset($final_ar[$key]);
            $final_ar[$key] = $temp_ar;
            $exist =1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($exist == 0)
    $final_arr[] = $temp_ar;
    //$parent_key = array_column($raw_ar,'ID', 'parentID');     
}
}
print_r($final_arr);
```

And I tried to code it with `sub_items` . But it helps to create array. But I don't know how to remove existing array once it modifies. It gives the result like this.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [pageTitle] => First [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/1 [parentID] => 0 [sub_items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [pageTitle] => Second [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/2 [parentID] => 6 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [pageTitle] => First [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/1 [parentID] => 0 [sub_items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [pageTitle] => Second [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/2 [parentID] => 6 ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [pageTitle] => First [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/1 [parentID] => 0 [sub_items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 8 [pageTitle] => Third [pageContent] => http://localhost/cms/3 [parentID] => 6 ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function formatArray($nonFormattedArray) {

    $formattedArray = [];
    $subItems = [];

    foreach ($nonFormattedArray as $item) {
        $pid = $item['parentID'];

        if ($pid != 0) {
            if (isset($subItems[$pid]))
                $subItems[$pid][] = $item;
            else
                $subItems[$pid] = [$item];
        } else
            $formattedArray[] = $item;
    }

    foreach ($formattedArray as $key => $parent) {
        resolveChild($formattedArray[$key], $subItems);
    }

    return $formattedArray;
}

function resolveChild(&$parent, &$subItems) {
    //return if no child
    if (!isset($subItems[$parent['ID']]))
        return $parent;

    foreach ($subItems[$parent['ID']] as $key => $child) {
        if (isset($parent['sub_items']))
            $parent['sub_items'][] = resolveChild($subItems[$parent['ID']][$key], $subItems);
        else
            $parent['sub_items'] = [resolveChild($subItems[$parent['ID']][$key], $subItems)];
     }

    return $parent;
}
```

Now, formatArray($nonFormattedArray) should return your desired answer.

This will be independent of the order of your parent and child items and will reduce the total iteration count and execution time.

This will produce an Array as deep as the inheritance in the data.

*Note that execution time will increase with the increment in inheritance level.*

Comment: Thanks, you made it.

Comment: one more clarification.  this list may have more sub lists.  Can you help me to call a nested functions to create any combination of nested arrays?.

Comment: Do you mean that the sub-items of your array may also contain sub-items?

Comment: yes. Like that way, it can work in any combination of sub-items and its sub-items

Comment: Okay. I will give it a try and update the answer when I have one :)

Comment: Sure, Thanks in advance and waiting for your update.

Answer (score 1):

So many code you have here.

Here's my version:

```
foreach ($raw_ar as $value) {
    if ($value['parentID'] == 0) {
        $final_ar[$value['ID']] = $value;
    }
}

foreach ($raw_ar as $value) {
    $parent_id = $value['parentID'];
    if (0 < $parent_id) {
        if (!isset($final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'])) {
            $final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'] = [];
        }

        $final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'][] = $value;
    }
}

$final_ar = array_values($final_ar);    // if you need 0-indexed array
```

If you're **100%** sure that parent items in your array come before child ones - you can join both `foreach`es into one:

```
foreach ($raw_ar as $value) {
    $parent_id = $value['parentID'];
    if ($parent_id == 0) {
        $final_ar[$value['ID']] = $value;
    } else {
        if (!isset($final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'])) {
            $final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'] = [];
        }

        $final_ar[$parent_id]['sub_items'][] = $value;
    }
}

$final_ar = array_values($final_ar);    // if you need 0-indexed array
```

Comment: @Anant yeah, fixed.

Comment: @u_mulder. Both has given some extended result close to my expected. But i don't want the array key 6 and 9 on the array key.  I mean the ID which has been used in the array key.  Can you help me to fix it with it. ?  That should not use the ID which is inside the array.

Comment: `array_values`. Didn't you see I wrote it in a first snippet?